# Certain users should get more close and delete votes

Tags: feature-request, voting, privileges, vote-to-close

20k+ users (or something) should get more close and delete votes. It is limiting when we are out of votes and come across questions to close or answers/questions to delete.

Flagging is cool, but sometimes we can take care of things, and because of the limited votes, and overwhelming number of questions, a few things slip through the cracks.

Is there a way to increase our number of votes or at least return our voting capacity faster?

Comment: You do, but it's not fast enough for you. ;P

Comment: @jrg: +1 it needs to be much faster :D

Comment: Is this on [meta.SE]?

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS: it probably should be.